# PHP foreach update the variable outside of foreach and use it inside again

Tags: php, foreach

I want to update the variable outside of the foreach scope and use it again in the condition inside it, but the variable in condition stays the same with the initial value. It gets updated outside, but the condition inside still uses the old value for comparing. How can the variable inside, used in condition get updated as well?

```
$total = 5.00000008;
for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
        if($total == $values[$i]){
            $total += 0.00000001;
        }
    }
```

I am referring to the $total variable inside if condition, it doesn't get updated.

Comment: what do you mean? which variable do you refer to?

Comment: your question was not clear.but your code works fine refer https://eval.in/1050113

Comment: @david If I'm understanding correctly, the OP is referring to the `$total` variable, stating that it's being updated but it doesn't appear to update for the sake of the conditional check. This sounds like classic floating point precision problem.

Comment: yes, the $total value in condition doesn't get updated. The $total value outside does, but in the condition it still uses the same value

Comment: I posted an answer with this argument being tested, @user2406735. I could not observe the situation you are mentioning.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. The problem was in float comparison. At some point it was increasing total, but again it is rounding it and didn't give he impression that the $total was updated every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, @NanThiyagan wrote:

> "your question was not clear.but your code works fine refer
>   eval.in/1050113"

Check out the output. It says 5.0000001. This might give you a hint that php automatically does something to round up your value.

Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
And pay attention to the part:

> "So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality."

In this article they approach the problem with an implicit precision: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/

Like this:

```
ini_set('precision', 17);
echo "0.1 + 0.2 = ". ( 0.1 + 0.2 ) ."\n";
$true = 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 ? "Equal" : "Not equal";
echo "0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3 => $true\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is not in comparison of values. The problem is that $total value doesn't get updated inside the foreach condition

Comment: I think that the problem is the same. It does get updated, but you can't see it due to the precision.

Comment: How come, it doesnt get updated? I don't think that's possible. Have you tried to output the $total on every iteration to see what's been printed? @JonKoeter, the precision doesn't affect it. 5.0000001 is equal to 5.00000010, which is why the last zero is not shown.

Comment: 5.0000001 might also be equal to 5.00000008

Comment: Makes you wonder why this wasn't somehow optimized. This error happens in all the php versions apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not be fully aware of what's happening inside the loop.

The variable `$total` is being updated every time the condition is **true**. And the condition variable `$total` is **updated as well**.

Here's an example so you can see it happening:

```
$values = [5.00000008, 5.00000009, 5.00000007];
$total = 5.00000008;

for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    echo ((string) __line__ . ' => ' . (string) $total . " (current total)\n");
    if($total === $values[$i]){
        echo ((string) __line__ . ' => ' . (string) $total . " (before increment)\n");
        $total += 0.00000001;
        echo ((string) __line__ . ' => ' . (string) $total . " (after increment)\n");
    }
}
```

And here's the code tested: https://3v4l.org/EJkNG

Answer (score 1):

> I am referring to the $total variable inside if condition, it doesn't get updated.

Of course it gets updated.

Simply echo $total inside the loop to find out.

```
<?php

$values = [5.00000007, 5.00000008, 5.00000009];
$total = 5.00000008;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    if ($total == $values[$i]) {
        $total += 0.00000001;
    }
    echo $total . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
5.00000008
5.00000009
5.0000001
```

See for yourself at https://3v4l.org/RBHa3